# Return render in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Is it bad to do return render? I am doing this to NOT also allow a redirect.

```
def create
    @patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])
    if  !@patient.save
      @patient.user.password = ''
      @patient.user.password_confirmation = ''
      return render is_admin? ? 'new_admin' : 'new'
    else
      #Fire off an e-mail
      PatientMailer.welcome_email(@patient).deliver
    end

    if current_user == @patient
      sign_in @patient
    else
      redirect_to patients_path
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Writing it like this makes it look the `render` returns a meaningful value that is then returned by create and used by the code that calls `create`, which is not the case. So instead I would write:

```
render is_admin? ? 'new_admin' : 'new'
return
```

This makes it clear that `render` is solely used for its side effects and `create` does not return a value (other than `nil`).

Answer (score 1):

There are two sensible ways to write that function.

The first way, with the early return, treats the special case more like an error condition:

```
def create
  @patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])
  if  !@patient.save
    @patient.user.password = ''
    @patient.user.password_confirmation = ''
    render is_admin? ? 'new_admin' : 'new'
    return
  end

  # Fire off an e-mail
  PatientMailer.welcome_email(@patient).deliver

  if current_user == @patient
    sign_in @patient
  else
    redirect_to patients_path
  end
end
```

The other way outlines all the possible outcomes:

```
def create
  @patient = Patient.new(params[:patient])
  if  !@patient.save
    @patient.user.password = ''
    @patient.user.password_confirmation = ''
    render is_admin? ? 'new_admin' : 'new'
  else
    # Fire off an e-mail
    PatientMailer.welcome_email(@patient).deliver
    if current_user == @patient
      sign_in @patient
    else
      redirect_to patients_path
    end
  end
end
```

I personally have a slight preference for the first way, since the failure to save is more like an error.  Your original code, which is a hybrid of the two, feels awkward.